# Almost purity for perfectoid fields applied on a computation of Galois cohomology.

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

Let $K=\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})$ and $C:=\widehat{\overline{\mathbf{Q}_P}}$. When I wrote an answer for a question [a question answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4822001/463468), I have in my mind that

> "$\widehat{K}$ is a  perfectoid fields will imply for example
> $H^i(G_K, O_C)$ is almost zero for $i>0$"

as a result of some "almost purity for for perfectoid fields".

I then searched and find for example [a lecture notes](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/notes.pdf), putting Corollary 185 as a consequence of Theorem 183. **I am fine to use Corollary 185 to conclude** (as in my answer linked). But I didn't see how can I directly use the fact "$\widehat{K}$ is a perfectoid field + almost purity for for perfectoid fields" to conclude. More precisely,

> Question: in [a lecture notes](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/notes.pdf), how does Theorem 183 imply Corollary 185?

Somehow Theorem 183 tells that "$L/\widehat{K}$ is almost finite etale", but in Corollary 185 one needs somehow "$L/K$ is almost finite etale."

> Or similar Question: Would "$L/\widehat{K}$ being almost finite etale for any finite extension $L/\widehat{K}$" imply (removing the completion) "$M/K$ is almost finite etale for any finite extension $M/K$"?

Thank you for remarks, perhaps this is stupid and the answer is very direct.

Comment: The second question seems to have positive answer, an evidence is that $G_K\simeq G_{\widehat{K}}$ in that setting. See for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794371/absolute-galois-group-of-the-p-adic-completion-of-a-valuation-field).